# Performing IDW for multiple Z field from attribute using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, inverse-distance-weighted, runtimeerror

I have data with multiple columns as 1996_1, 1997_1, etc. I need to perform IDW for each column values and save it. I am a beginner with arcpy. Please help!
The code is as follows:

```
import arcpy, os

from arcpy import env

from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "100%"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

env.workspace = "F:\Python\Arcpy"

inPointFeatures = "F:\Python\Arcpy\fluctpnt_UTM.shp"

zfield = ["1996_1","1997_1"]

for z in zfield:

    outIDW_1 = Idw(inPointFeatures, zfield,0.002298707671,2,RadiusVariable(10,15000))
    outIDW_1.save("004_{}.tif".format(z))
```

but i get this error as follows:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 2632, in Idw
    in_barrier_polyline_features)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 2624, in Wrapper
    in_barrier_polyline_features)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

[Refer_data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1srggoBmgPGRFwKHBtqP1SvnLdRGvCtd3)

Comment: @umbe1987 Thank you for answering my question. The script is still not working by replacing z. ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000865: Input point features: F:\Python\Arcpyluctpnt_UTM.shp does not exist. ERROR 001000: Z value field: Field 1996_1 does not exist Failed to execute (Idw).

Comment: You should add comments below my answer in order to let me know it, otherwise I could not be notified when you're writing. Anyway, your errors seem to point that you have defined your path to your shapefile the wrong way. `F:\Python\Arcpyluctpnt_UTM.shp` should be `F:\Python\Arcpy\fluctpnt_UTM.shp`. tyr changing your `inPointFeatures` variable like so: `inPointFeatures = r"F:\Python\Arcpy\fluctpnt_UTM.shp"` (I put an "r" in front of the path)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem might be that these lines:

```
for z in zfield:

    outIDW_1 = Idw(inPointFeatures, zfield,0.002298707671,2,RadiusVariable(10,15000))
    outIDW_1.save("004_{}.tif".format(z))
```

should look like these lines:

```
for z in zfield:

    outIDW_1 = Idw(inPointFeatures, z,0.002298707671,2,RadiusVariable(10,15000))
    outIDW_1.save("004_{}.tif".format(z))
```

You need to replace variable `z_field` with `z` within your loop, otherwise you are using a list of field names (`["1996_1","1997_1"]`) as input to the IDW z_field parameter.

Also, I would change the name of your output raster to avoid numbers at first place, as suggested in the [Output raster formats and names](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/performing-analysis/output-raster-formats-and-names.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F3B1F36334264586A14E67C2C4A36E3D):

> It is generally recommended that you have the first letter of a raster
>   name be a character instead of a number or symbol.